# Review UI Widget from Google Play

Tags: android-widget, android, review

I need to implement a Reviews widget in my application, similar to that seen in Google Play. Image Below:

[image]

Are there any components our there that make it easier to do this? It would save time & trouble of implementing my own version.

Thanks

Comment: Hai.. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Vijay hi yes i did but i had to go with a custom layout for it. Linearlayout and Relativelayouts

Comment: How did you calculate the ratings?? Can you post the calculation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a custom layout for this as cmota recommended.

The labels for the stars are a series of TextViews within a Relative layout

The rating bars are Imageviews in a Linearlayouts.

Code snippet:

ImageView ratingOne =  (ImageView) ratingsView.findViewById(R.id.ratingOne);

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratings_length_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:background="@color/orange" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

Each imageview has a fixed height : for example i use 15dp above

The width of the imageview is the my rating count

Then i change the layoutParams for each imageView according to the values

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(myRatingCount, ratingOne.getHeight());

ratingOne.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Answer (score 3):

I would create a custom layout for that.

A TextField for stars information, a progress bar to show the number of stars and another TextField to show the number of ratings. Everything rapped on a LinearLayout (orientation = horizontal) for proper alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `RatingBar` in android.

some sample links

- http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/
- http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/08/android-ratingbar-example.html
- http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/ratingbar/android-rating-bar-example/

Comment: that is not for reviews, its a rating bar. I clearly attached an image above.